# Extract Email Data such as "From" and "To"

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, extract

I want to go into a specified folder in Outlook and based on a variable (value/named range in Excel) extract data from emails (To, Subject, etc.).

I can extract only the "Subject" and "Size" data of the emails.

If I try to pull in the "To" data, for example, it comes up with

> "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method error.

```vb
Sub FetchEmailData()

    Dim appOutlook As Object
    Dim olNs As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim iRow As Integer
     
    'Get/create Outlook Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set appOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If appOutlook Is Nothing Then
        Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
     
    Set olNs = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNs.Folders("Mailbox_name").Folders("Inbox").Folders("XYZ").Folders("2017").Folders("04. April").Folders("Etc")

    'Clear
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells.Delete

    'Build headings:
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A1:D1") = Array("Sender_Email_Address", "Subject", "To", "Size")

    For iRow = 1 To olFolder.Items.Count
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow, 1).Select
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow, 1) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow, 2) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow, 3) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).To
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow, 4) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Size
    Next iRow
     
End Sub
```

How could I extract fields such as "From" and "To"?

Also, if my `Set olFolder` value is a named range in Excel that dynamically changes with the date (`=Today()`) and uses `Folder_Location` as the named range in Excel, would it be correct to write;

```
Set olFolder = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Range("Folder_Location")
```

Where

```
Folder_Location = olNs.Folders("Mailbox_name").Folders("Inbox").Folders("XYZ").Folders("2017").Folders("04. April").Folders("Etc")
```

This errors when I attempt to link it to `olFolder`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I had the same problem recently and was able to figure it out after going through what you had done already.

There were only a few changes I needed to make; first I set my selected folder to be my inbox for simplicities sake:

```
Set olFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 == Inbox for some reason
```

Then, I changed the headings you made just a bit for my readability (not a functional change):

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:D1") = Array("Sender Email Address:", "Subject:", "To:", "Size:")
```

Lastly to get the functionality you were looking for, a small change needed to be made to your indicies in your "Cells" parameter within your for loop:

```
For iRow = 1 To olFolder.Items.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow + 1, 1) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow + 1, 2) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow + 1, 3) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).To
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow + 1, 4) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Size
```

Next iRow

That "+1" in there makes it so we don't overwrite our headers.  So the final version looks like this:

```
Sub FetchEmailData()

Dim appOutlook As Object
Dim olNs As Object
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olItem As Object
Dim iRow As Integer

' Get/create Outlook Application
On Error Resume Next
Set appOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If appOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set olNs = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 == Inbox for some reason

' Clear
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells.Delete

' Build headings:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A1:D1") = Array("Sender Email Address:", "Subject:", "To:", "Size:")

For iRow = 1 To olFolder.Items.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow + 1, 1) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow + 1, 2) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow + 1, 3) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).To
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(iRow + 1, 4) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Size
Next iRow

End Sub
```